# Prove A → (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B) using classical logic

Tags: propositional-calculus

I've tried to do this by assuming A, then using the law of excluded middle to get B ∨ ¬B. From here I plan on using or elimination to get A ∧ B then or introduction to get (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B). I can get a proof of B → A ∧ B but not a proof of ¬B → A ∧ B. Is it possible to get a proof of ¬B → A ∧ B from what I have or do I need to prove A → (A ∧ B) ∨ (A ∧ ¬B) a different way? Thank you.

Comment: Use the distributivity of $\land$ over $\lor$.

Comment: It is quite sumple with LEM; use Disjunction Elim on $B \lor \lnot B$ to get $(A \land B)$ and $(A \land \lnot B)$ respectively. The result will follow using Disjunction Intro.

Comment: Thank you, I understand how to get B → A ∧ B but how can I get ¬B → A ∧ B so I can use Disjunction Elim on B∨¬B to get A∧B

Comment: From $B$ to to $B → A ∧ B$ and then $B → (A ∧ B) \lor (A ∧  ¬B)$ and from $¬B$ to to $B → A ∧ ¬B$ and then $¬B → (A ∧ ¬B) \lor (A ∧  B)$. After that, conclude by Disjunction Elim with $B ∨ ¬B$.